# Using Item's name on an "if" in Android

Tags: android, arrays, spinner

I have a `Spinner` on an ActivityA:

```java
cmbOpciones1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.CmbOpciones1);
ArrayAdapter<?> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( this, R.array.exporal , android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);  
adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item);
cmbOpciones1.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

This is the array XML:

```xml
<string-array name="exporal">
    <item name="1">7:00 9:00am EXPRESIÓN ORAL Y ESCRITA</item>
    <item name="2">9:00 11:00am EXPRESIÓN ORAL Y ESCRITA</item>
</string-array>
```

I can send the selected items on the `Spinner` to another activity with this code:

```
//BotonSeleccionar
BotonPasar1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.VB1);
BotonPasar1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    //Preferences Materia 1

    SharedPreferences mypreferences1 = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = mypreferences1.edit();
    editor1.putString("Culo", cmbOpciones1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    editor1.commit();
```

On the other activity I have this code that receives the items of the array from the `Spinner`:

```java
//Materia 1
llegada1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1); 
llegada2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv2); 
SharedPreferences mypreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences mypreferences1 = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String teamnamestring = mypreferences.getString("Culo", "no_name");
String hola = mypreferences1.getString("Culoq","no_name");
llegada1.setText(teamnamestring);
llegada2.setText(hola);
```

Let's say I have several `Spinners` on ActivityA, and several `TextViews` receivers on the ActivityB. **What can I do to select an item of my array by its name?** For example, if I want all the items with the name "1" to go to the first `TextView` and with the name "3" to go to the "X" `TextView`, is there a way to do this with an `if` statement? I want to make it clear: I want to call an item by its name on the array XML example.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is following methode which can be called on all Java String: `equalsIgnoreCase(string)`

An example with an if statement:

```
    String test = "test";
    String test2 = "tEsT";
    String test3 = "tester"

    if(test.equalsIgnoreCase(test2) {
        // this will be true;
    }
    if(test3.equalsIgnoreCase(test2) {
        // this will be false;
    }
```